# How Smart Target updates the "Views" counter in experiments?

Tags: dxa, web8.5, smarttarget, dxa-1.7

We have a .NET web application using DXA 1.7 and SDL Web 8.5, we have configured XO and we're having trouble with the "Views" counter in experiments. The "Conversions" counter is working fine but the "Views" counter is always 0.

[image]

Anyone knows how SmartTarget updates the views counter in experiments?

Comment: I can only assume this is data from Google Analytics, just as it is for conversions... (I know, not a real answer).

Comment: Are you using the provided controls or your own, to query for the experiments on your website?

Comment: Also, are you using the in-process assemblies or the new OData ones?

Comment: We're not using the in-process assembies, we're using the new ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found that the error in the views counter was an error in the Experience Optimization DXA module.

SDL support confirmed it, and to fix the problem, a hotfix will be released on January 2018.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that it is done automatically by the Query control. So when the Experiment is rendered, a view will be tracked. The tracking is done through the AnalyticsManager which in turn uses a configurable provider to do the tracking and retrieval of data. A default Google Analytics provider is given out-of-the-box.

If you are using the API directly instead of the controls, you will need to track the view yourself, by calling the TrackView method on an AnalyticsManager instance.

Comment: Hi Peter, we're not using the API directly and the tracking isn't working, I've tried to configure it in the DXA Example Site with same result. Number of views doesn't work, the google analytics event for tracking views isn't been created in the Google Analytics account.

Comment: We might need to solve this through Support, in that case. It could be that you are missing some configuration in GA or that Google changed something that broke it. Either way, we're probably not going to be able to solve it in these comments.

Comment: Ok, thank you Peter! We already have a ticket opened (00318212)